# How to specify newxreg in prediction model of ARIMA?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, prediction

I have fit the model below to my time series data.  The `xreg` consists of a time vector that goes from 1 through 1000 and of 12 indicator variables (1 or 0) that represent the month.  The data that I'm dealing with has some strong weekly and monthly seasonal patterns.

```
fit <- arima(x, order = c(3, 0, 0),
    seasonal = list(order = c(1, 0, 1), period = 7),   
    xreg = cbind(t, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5,
    M6, M7, M8, M9, M10, M11, M12), include.mean = FALSE,
    transform.pars = TRUE,
    fixed = NULL, init = NULL,
        method = c("CSS-ML", "ML", "CSS"),
        optim.method = "BFGS",
        optim.control = list(), kappa = 1e6)
```

At this time I'm trying to figure out how I can predict 14 values for the month of January (`M1=1`).
So when I use the predict function in R, I think I need to specify in the newxreg portion that I want `M1=1` and `M2,...,M12=0` for my prediction - correct?
I've played around with the code, but I couldn't get it to work and I was not able to find very detailed information about the newxreg portion of the predict formula online.

Can anyone explain to me how I can get predictions for one partigular month, say January?
And how do I need to note that in the newxreg part of the predict function?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

I have finally found a way out and wanted to post it - in case it helps someone else.
So basically, newxreg should be a matrix that contains values of the regressors that you want predictions for.
So in my case, my regressors were all 1 or 0 (coded variables) to specify a particular month.
So what I did is I created a matrix of 0's and 1's to be used as my newxreg.
What I did is I defined a matrix mx, and then in the predict function I set newxreg=mx.  I made sure that the number of rows of mx>= number of rows of n.ahead.

pred <- predict(fit,n.ahead=n, newxreg=mx)

Hope this is helpful for others as well!